# Azure: how to trigger a nodejs webjob when there is a message in the queue?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-webjobs

I've created a webjob written in node. I wonder if there is a way to trigger this webjob to run whenever there is a message coming to the queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out the [azure-webjobs-sdk-script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) repo where we're developing a solution to this very problem.

The repo is new, so doc and help are still coming online, but you can clone it and run the **Host.Node** sample project which demonstrates various Node.js triggered functions, including [a queue triggered function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/master/sample/Host.Node/scripts/queueTrigger.js) :) This library has already been tested deployed to Azure and works.

Please log any issues/feedback on the issues list of the repo and we'll address them :)

Comment: Of course you'd make this public. Use Mathew's thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at Mathew's post for a new thing we're working on with the SDK. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script

<strike>Not yet with the WebJobs SDK.</strike> You can build a continuous Job and keep [fetching](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/#how-to-peek-at-the-next-message). If you wanted to build something kinda sane, you could probably do something like:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var queueService = azure.createQueueService(),
  queueName = 'taskqueue';

// Poll every 5 seconds to avoid consuming too many resources
setInterval(function() {
  queueService.getMessages(queueName, {}, function(error, serverMessages) {
    if (!error) {
      // For each message
      serverMessages.foreach(function(i) {
        // Do something
        console.log(i.messagetext);
        // Delete Message
        queueService.deleteMessage(queueName, i.messageid, i.popreceipt,
          function(error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }); //end deleteMessage
      }); // end foreach
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

You'll want to look at the JSDocs they have on [azure.github.io](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/QueueService.html#getMessages) to learn how to do things like grab multiple message and increase the "blocking" time which is defaulted to 30 seconds.

Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is exactly what i got atm. I'm looking at Matt's solution now.